# Java string concatenation - is there a better way?

Tags: java, string, concatenation

Just a quick form question. In the following code, is there a better way to concatinate the strings (i.e. can I just set tmpError equal to the new string rather than adding it?)

```
public void validate () throws Exception {
    String tmpError = "";
    if(paramA == null) tmpError = tmpError + "paramA was not set";

    if(paramB == null) tmpError = tmpError + "paramB was not set";

    if(paramC == null) tmpError = tmpError + "paramC was not set";


    if(!tmpError.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        tmpError = "error occured" + tmpError;
        throw new Exception(tmpError);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would always advise the use of the StringBuilder

something like this:

```
public void validate() throws Exception {
    StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder();
    if(paramA == null)
        error.append("paramA was not set");

    if(paramB == null)
        error.append("paramB was not set");

    if(paramC == null)
        error.append("paramC was not set");


    if(error.length() > 0) {

        throw new Exception("error occured " + error.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your answer, but I'd factor it so that you are appending only " paramA", " paramB" and " paramC".  Then I'd throw with "Error - parameters not set:" + error.toString().

Answer (score 4):

It can be easily improved in efficiency by using [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Due to the immutable nature of `String`, every time you  use the addition (`+`) operator for String concatenation, a new `String` object is allocated (it also does when using `String.concat()`).

`StringBuilder` keeps an internal character array, so that concatenation operations work on that array and only one `String` object is allocated when you call its `toString()` method. Use its `append()` method to append text to the end of the String, and use `insert()` with offset 0 to prepend text.

However, you should also take into account readability. Dasblinkenlight made a good point in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15545243/851811). And as Anthony has already pointed out, you could also use the `+=` compound assignment operator to enhance readability.

```
public void validate () throws Exception {
    StringBuilder tmpError = new StringBuilder();
    if(paramA == null) tmpError.append("paramA was not set");

    if(paramB == null) tmpError.append("paramB was not set");

    if(paramC == null) tmpError.append("paramC was not set");


    if(tmpError.length() > 0){
        tmpError.insert(0,"error occured");
        throw new Exception(tmpError.getString());
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be better to use the `length()` method of the StringBuilder class to check whether or not it's empty, rather than comparing it to an empty string literal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `+=` (addition/concatenation and assignment) operator:

```
if(paramA == null) tmpError += "paramA was not set";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not efficient, because with all three params missing you will create four string objects. You would be better off appending to a single [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) object.

However, this is error reporting code which gets executed only when your code detects a programming error. Efficiency does not matter much in situations like that, because they are not supposed to happen in the first place. Use whatever you believe to be easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
public void validate () throws Exception {
    String tmpError = "";
    if(paramA == null) tmpError += "paramA was not set";

    if(paramB == null) tmpError += "paramB was not set";

    if(paramC == null) tmpError += "paramC was not set";


    if(!tmpError.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        tmpError = "error occured" + tmpError;
        throw new Exception(tmpError);
    }
}
```

Or alternatively, you can use a `StringBuilder` as pointed out by Xavi, but to me that would only make sense, if you were appending text inside some sort of loop.

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way to concatenation two strings is concat function of String class.

```
public void validate () throws Exception {
    String tmpError = "";

    if(paramA == null) tmpError = tmpError.concat("paramA was not set");
    if(paramB == null) tmpError = tmpError.concat("paramB was not set");
    if(paramC == null) tmpError = tmpError.concat("paramC was not set");
    if(!tmpError.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        tmpError = "error occured".concat(tmpError);
        throw new Exception(tmpError);
    }
}
```

Comment: `concat()` will create a new `String` object at each call, just like `+` would.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than any of the above, you might want to use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [Preconditions](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PreconditionsExplained).  Then you could write code like this:

```
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.*;
...
public void doSomething(String strA, String strB) {
  checkNotNull(strA, "strA is missing");
  checkArgument(strB.length() >= 6, "strB is too short");
  ...
}
```

If the check fails, then an `Exception` is thrown.  It might not be quite as succinct as your original solution, but your intention is semantically obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something as below
public void validate () throws Exception {

```
public void validate () throws Exception {
    String tmpError = "";
    if(paramA == null) tmpError += "paramA was not set";
    if(paramB == null) tmpError += "paramB was not set";
    if(paramC == null) tmpError += "paramC was not set";

    if(!(tmpError.trim()).equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        tmpError = "error occured" + tmpError;
        throw new Exception(tmpError);
    }
}
```

See I've used `+=` and trimmed the `tmpError` variable before checking its empty.

I don't think here you don't need to worry much about `StringBuilder` as not much memory is being handled in this scenario.

If you are insisting on StringBuilder then you may do something as below

```
public void validate () throws Exception {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if(paramA == null) sb.append("paramA was not set");
    if(paramB == null) sb.append("paramB was not set");
    if(paramC == null) sb.append("paramC was not set");

    if(!(sb.toString().trim()).equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        sb.Insert(0,"error occured");
        throw new Exception(sp.toString());
    }
}
```